# How do I call a method from another class without creating an object of the class?

Tags: java, swing, class, methods

I want to call a method from another class that has `extends JFrame` in its class. I have another class that has an actionevent listener. I want to call the method from the other class, but I cannot since it wants me to create a new object for my class.

I tried using     `Frame frame = new Frame();` But it creates a new frame completely. I need for my program to declare a method within the class without creating the class. My method in the other class is not static. I cant show the code right now.

Comment: Show your code ?

Comment: Unless you are adding menu(item)s to the JMenuBar, there are very few reasons to extend a JFrame. Instead, extend JPanel and when you want to instantiate add it to a JFrame (or a JWindow/JDialog)

Comment: As far as this method you are trying to access: There is a common swing pattern called "Model-View-Controller". If the method has to do with the data behind the display, the method should be in the model. If the method is an implementation of ActionListener, this should go in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

When there is a frame declared, have the void in the same class and use `className.function();` The frame should be declared somewhere that is not in a method.